# Возможен ли выход в интернет программе исключительно через определённый сетевой адаптер?

Tags: windows, маршрутизация, adapter, firewall

Можно ли это провернуть? Например, чтобы определённый .exe имел доступ в интернет только пока включён определённый адаптер, а при его отключении доступ в сеть пропадал только для этой программы. (имеется несколько адаптеров, экзешник не должен иметь возможность выходить в интернет через них)
У некоторых программ, таких как qBittorrent, такая функция есть в настройках, но у моей нету, можно ли средствами windows воспроизвести эту опцию?

Comment: Уточните, вы имеете в виду приложению которое вы сами разрабатываете или какому-то постороннему? Если первое, то какие язык и технология программирования?

Comment: Постороннему приложению. Онлайн игре.

Answer (score 1):

Привязать можно попробовать, но работать не будет: Windows автоматически будет отправлять пакеты по пути с лучшей метрикой, поскольку в системе нет ни Load Balancing, ни PBR.

Поэтому решения будут базироваться либо на прокси (например, HandyCache), либо на виртуалке, либо на каком-либо специфическом решении а ля [ForceBindIP](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip).

Вполне возможно, что как раз последнее решение вас и устроит: устанавливаете ForceBindIP, меняете свойства ярлыка вашей программы, добавляя перед её командной строкой: "C:\Program Files\ForceBindIP\ForceBindIP.exe" xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" (вместо C:\Program Files\ForceBindIP может быть иной путь, смотря куда вы поставили ForceBindIP, а xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - IP нужного вам адаптера).
Т.е.  в итоге в ярлыке у вас должно получиться что-то типа:

```
"C:\Program Files\ForceBindIP\ForceBindIP.exe" 192.168.1.23 "C:\Program Files\Bandites\game.exe"
```