# Доступ в интернет для определенной программы для определенного подключения

Tags: windows, сеть, windows-10

Есть машина с `windows 10` на борту, для доступа в интернет есть локальное подключение (через обычный модем), оно же офисная сеть и дает доступ к сетевым папкам и др., так же есть доступ в интернет через юсб модем на этой же машине.

Задача:
Есть определенная программа, так вот, нужно, чтобы при работе с сетью она использовала ресурсы только ЮСБ модема. Конечно же, первым делом приходит решение в голову - отключить локальную сеть и останется только одно подключение через модем. Но, тогда пропадет доступ к сетевым папкам, принтерам,  другим делам. Собственно вопрос, возможно ли при активных двух подключениях к интернету (локалка и юсб модем), сделать так, чтобы программа работала с интернетом, только через юсб модем и при этом оставить работоспособной основную сеть?

*p.s. Если подумать логически - то конечно приходит на ум, что винда может обрабатывать сигнал только с одного адаптера (((. Но может есть способ.......*

Comment: Ну программу вряд ли, а вот [приоритет](https://ip-calculator.ru/blog/ask/upravlenie-prioritetom-setevyh-adapterov-v-windows-10/) на адаптер перебросить вроде как можно

Comment: Вы также можете на адаптери локальной сети очистить поля Основной шлюз (откуда ПК брать интернет) и если прописаны DNS

Comment: Если предыдущий совет не работает, то можно изменить таблицу маршрутизации, для этого есть команда `route`

Comment: Намек понятен, теперь сложность только в одном - автоматизировать этот процесс ))). Чтобы пользователь не тыкал шлюзы, согласно моей инструкции )

Comment: Взгляните сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/652133/